# Error: enum "e_Sides" has no member "Left"

Tags: c++, enums

I have created an enum in GlobalGameEnums.h. I have included this header in Board.h where I have declared on my class but it won't let me use the enum values.

The GlobalGameEnums.h:

```
#ifdef GLOBALGAMEENUMS_H
#define GLOBALGAMEENUMS_H

enum class e_Side
{
    Right,
    Left
};

#endif
```

And the Board.h:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
    .
    .
    #include "GlobalGameEnums.h"

    class Board
    {
    public:
    Board(int i_boardSize, int i_lowBound, int i_highBound);
    ~Board();

    int MakePlayerMove(enum e_Side i_sideTaken )
    {
        switch (i_sideTaken)
        {
        case e_Side::Left:
            break;
        case e_Side::Right:
            break;
        }
    }

    private:
    std::vector<Cell> m_cellVector;
    };

#endif
```

In method MakePlayerMove's declaration it does recognizes e_Side type but in the method body it gives me an error for using Left/Right (`Error: enum "e_Side" has no member "Left"`).

I have tried a lot of configurations and searched for an old solution but couldn't get it working.

Comment: One way to avoid `ifndef` errors could be to make use of [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) instead if you have the support for it

Answer (score 5):

The header guard in your enum header is wrong.  You have #ifdef instead of #ifndef.

Comment: If this is the case, shouldn't it have given an earlier error on the `MakePlayerMove` parameter?

Comment: @MarkRansom: This is way back in my C-brain, but I believe a parameter written with the enum specificier acts as a forward declaration.  He's creating a new, nested enum type.

Answer (score -1):

For pre C++11, declare your enum like this:

```
#ifndef GLOBALGAMEENUMS_H
#define GLOBALGAMEENUMS_H

namespace mygame
{
    enum e_Side {
        Right,
        Left
    };
}

#endif
```

Don't use 'class' in your declaration of enum.
Your Board class should look like this:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
...
#include "GlobalGameEnums.h"
...

    namespace mygame
    {
        class Board
            {
            public:
            Board(int i_boardSize, int i_lowBound, int i_highBound);
            ~Board();

            int MakePlayerMove(e_Side temp_sideTaken)
            {
                e_Side i_sideTaken = Left;
                switch (i_sideTaken)
                {
                case Left:
                    break;
                case Right:
                    break;
                }
            }

            private:
            std::vector<Cell> m_cellVector;
            };
    }

    #endif
```

I'd also encourage to use name spaces.

Comment: enum class is a C++11 feature.  It's perfectly valid.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think this question is particular to c++11